# $F^{m\times n}\cong F^{mn}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Show that $F^{m\times n}$ is isomorphic to $F^{mn}.$

$F^{n}$ here is the $n$-tuple space formed by the field $F$ and $F^{m\times n}$ the space of $m\times n$ matrices over $F.$

Attempt: If $A\in F^{m\times n},a\in F^{mn},$ consider the mapping $T(A)\to a$ such that $A_{ij}=a_{ni+j-n},1\le i\le m,1\le j\le n.$ (I guessed this formula through trial and error, I don't even know if this is right.)

It looks like I need to show that $ni+j-n$ only runs from $1$ to $mn,$(I was able to do this.) and also for $(p,q)\ne (r,s),$ I want $np+q-n\ne nr+s-n.$(**Looks trivial, but how to do this?**)

$T$ is well- defined(Provided I show what is written above).

$T$ is one-one.Let $A,B\in F^{m\times n}$ and $a=T(A),b=T(B).$ Suppose $A\ne B.$ Then there exists $i,j,1\le i\le m,1\le j\le n$ such that $A_{ij}\ne B_{ij}.$ This implies $a_{ni+j-n}\ne b_{ni+j-n}\implies a\ne b$

$T$ is onto since for each $a\in F^{mn},$ consider the matrix $A$ with $A_{ij}=a_{ni+j-n},1\le i\le m,1\le j\le n.$

> I need help with that inequality. More importantly, is my proof correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $ni + j - n$ as $n(i-1) + j$, and note that $1 \leq j \leq n$. Then $j$ is the modulus of $n(i-1) + j$ mod $n$, and $i$ is the integer part upon division by $n$. If you set $n(i-1)+j = n(k-1)+l$, then you must have $j=l$ since $1 \leq j, l \leq n$, and then you can see that $i=k$, as you wanted.

Otherwise, your proof looks complete.